# Reactivating Windows 8 after reformat

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I am looking to reformat my drive and I was wondering if I was able to use my Windows 8 pro with media center product key obtained from the Windows 8 promotion. With the email that I received my product key, it says: "Make sure you activate your product by January 13 2013". Considering I've already activated it, does that mean I can reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as you have activated for the first time before the given date. I personally have used my Windows Key from a Windows 8 promotion as well on multiple installations across 3 of my Virtual Machines (For testing purposes).